# How to setup nginx config .well-known/acme-challenge with a proxy to Django?

Tags: django, nginx

I am very confused with the Nginx .well-known/acme-challenge configuration and how it works with a proxy for Django.
Here is my frontend config with is working:

```
server {
     listen 80;
     server_name myserve.com;
     root /var/www/html/myapp_frontend/myapp/;
     index index.html;
     location / {
          try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
     }
     location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
          allow all;
          root /var/www/html/myapp_frontend/myapp/;
     }

     return 301 https://myserver.com$request_uri;
 }
```

So, on the frontend I have no problem to define: root /var/www/html/myapp_frontend/myapp/;

Now I can run the acme script like this:

```
/root/.acme.sh/acme.sh --issue -d myserver.com -w /var/www/html/myapp_frontend/myapp/
```

It is working fine.
But I have issues with my Django backend because the nginx config uses a proxy:

```
upstream myapp {
     server backend:8000;
}

server {

     listen 80;
     server_name api.myserver.com;

     location / {
          proxy_pass http://myapp;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_redirect off;
     }

     return 301 https://api.myserver.com$request_uri;
 }
```

Notice that I do not really have a configuration for the folder "/var/www/html/myapp_backend/myapp/" as I have on the frontend config, because now I'm using a proxy.

Now I can't run acme script like this:

```
/root/.acme.sh/acme.sh --issue -d myserver.com -w /var/www/html/myapp_backend/myapp/
```

How do I configure the folder for the SSL provider to be able to check my backend?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible to do it only in Nginx configuration, but I came to the conclusion that using a proxy it was Django who should create a url to /.well-known/acme-challenge/

I basically set a URL like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^acme-challenge/(?P<file_name>[\w\-]+)$', get_challenge),
]
```

and

```
urlpatterns = [
   ...
   path('.well-known/', include('myapp.wellknonw.urls')),
]
```

Notice that to accept multiple file names I use this: (?P<file_name>[\w-]+)$

And my views are like this:

```
@require_GET
def get_challenge(request, file_name=None):
    lines = []
    if file_name:
        path = f'{BASE_DIR}/myapp/.well-known/acme-challenge/{file_name}'
    try:
        with open(path) as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            f.close()
    except:
        return HttpResponse("File not found!",
                            status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    return HttpResponse("".join(lines), content_type="text/plain")
```

In docker my volume to: /myapp/.well-known/acme-challenge/

is mounted to: /var/www/html/myapp_backend/myapp/

Answer (score 0):

create `.well-known` folder in your website public folder in this case mine is
`/home/admin/domains/mysite.com/public_html/site/public/.well-known`

Add a new location to your Ngnix config

```
  location /.well-known/ {
        root /home/admin/domains/mysite.com/public_html/site/public;
  }
```

Add this to your `settings.py`

```
WELL_KNOWN_URL = '/.well-known/'

WELL_KNOWN_ROOT = '/home/admin/domains/mysite.com/public_html/site/public/.well-known'
```

add these imports to your django urls.py
you can either add it in your project urls.py or app urls.py if its has no any other path prefix

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import path
```

add this to your `urlpatterns = []`

```
urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(
    settings.WELL_KNOWN_URL, document_root=settings.WELL_KNOWN_ROOT
)
```

then you can add another folder `acme-challenge`